# Is there a way to display images from raspistill on a webpage without saving them on the file system first?

Tags: camera, web-server, php

I'm working on a web page that I would like to be able to constantly display images taken by the raspberry pi camera (about one per second) in real time. my problem is I don't want to save, read, then delete image after image on my SD card.

I understand that raspistill can send output to stdout.
Is there a way to get output from the raspberry pi camera to a php script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a ram disk if the point is to stop SD card wear and tear.

E.g.

sudo mkdir /ram # create mount point (a one off command)

sudo mount -osize=100m tmpfs /ram -t tmpfs # create ram disk at each boot

This will create a 100 MB ram disk accessible at /ram.  Save your photos to /ram, upload, delete.  No SD card wear and tear.